# unexpected Indent and break out of loop in game code

Tags: python, return, break

i am new to python as you may be able to tell with this question. I am currently building a Rock, Paper, Scissors game to later include into a bigger program i am working on in python 3.4.  the problem i am having is in the code listed below.

```
def computerPlayer(): #randomly selects a rock paper or scissor for computer hand
    c = random.randint(0, 2)
if c==0:
    y=('rock')
if c==1:
    y=('scissors')
if c==2:
    y==('paper')
     return y
```

in front of the bottom line return y i am getting a unexpected Indent error, i have tried correcting this over the past day now with no results, if i move it forward i get 'return' outside function, but when i move it back i get the unexpected indent, I am honestly at a complete loss here and im not sure where to go. Any help is great thanks.

the above problem is now fixed, but i know have a break outside of loop error. it is appearing at the end of my code now. any help is great thank you.

```
    again = raw_input('do you wish to try again? (yes\no)\n :') #Ask the user if they want play again
if again == ('yes') or again == ('sure') or again == ('okay'):
    print ('')
elif again == ('no') or again == ('nah') or again == ('nope') or again == ('screw you') or again == ('screw it'):
    print ('FINE THEN!!! =^( \n               (Enter>>>game()<<< if you change your mind)')
#breaks the loop 
break 

game()
```

Comment: Indentation is important in Python; only one line is inside the function.

Comment: Not an answer to your question -- you could also write this function as `return random.choice(['rock', 'scissors', 'paper'])`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well, a one-line implementation **is** an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def computerPlayer():
    '''
    Randomly selects a rock paper or scissor for computer hand
    '''
    c = random.randint(0, 2)
    if c == 0:
       y = ('rock')
    if c == 1:
       y = ('scissors')
    if c == 2:
       y = ('paper')
    return y
```

Indentation is important in python, it shows where your methods and control flows start and end. In your previous code, the `if` statements were not indented under the method and so python could not tell that it was apart of the `computerPlayer()` function.

According to PEP8 ( a style guide for python ) proper indentation is 4 spaces. For more information on PEP8 and its view on indentation, check here:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: Have you left the `y==` in there on purpose?

Comment: @JimmyThompson No didnt. I was just focusing on the indentation part of the OP's question. Just updated it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach just added some explanation.

Comment: thank you very much that seemed to work, still having a problem at the end of the code with a break being outside the loop, but ill see if i can figure that out. thanks again!!

Comment: @Gnels85 no problem!  Feel free to post another question if you get stuck.

Comment: @agconti i have added the last part of code that im ahveing problems with above, it is saying the break is outside the loop? but i thought it was supposed to be in order to end the loop?

Comment: @Gnels85 hey, `break` needs a loop to work. I'm not sure exactly whats going on but ask a question again with a sample of the code and I'm sure we can figure it out.